# Polynomial-Reduction (Clique)

Tags: graph-theory

If we define the language 2CLIQUE = {(G; t) | G is a graph with at least 2 different cliques of size t}.

Now if 2CLIQUE ∈ P then CLIQUE should be ∈ P?

I need a bit of help understanding this.

Comment: Suppose you put two copies of the input graph beside each other...